# True, False: $N(T^*T)=N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is finite dimensional inner product space over $F$ and $T$ is a linear transformation.

True, False: $N(T^*T)=N(T)$
I think it is true.
If $x \in N(T)$ then $T(x)=0$ and $T^*T(x)=T^*(0)=0$.
If $x \in N(T^*T)$ then $T^*T(x)=0$ and $T(x)=T^*(0)=0$.
Is that right?

One more question.
Let $F=C$ and $T$ be normal. If $T$ is a projection then $T$ is an orthogonal projection.
I think it is true but don't know how to prove it...

Comment: @amWhy You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering your first question(I dont think your arguements are perfectly correct)

You need to show that $N(T^*T)=N(T)$. For this you need to show that $N(T^*T)\subseteq N(T)$ and $N(T)\subseteq N(T^*T)$.

$2$nd one is trivial because if $x\in N(T)\Rightarrow Tx=0 \Rightarrow T^*Tx=0\Rightarrow x\in N(T^*T)\Rightarrow N(T)\subseteq N(T^*T)$

For the first one you have to use the fact that $V$ is a inner product space. iF $x\in N(T^*T) \Rightarrow T^*Tx=0\Rightarrow x^*T^*Tx=0\Rightarrow \langle Tx,Tx\rangle=0$ and as $V$ is a inner product space so $Tx=0$.This implies $N(T^*T)\subseteq N(T)$.

So we are done.